# use extra button for changing month in asp.net webcalendar

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to customize the webcalendar-element in asp.net with c#.net

What I would like to do: For certain users, disable the possibility to view previous months - but they should still be able to see all of the upcoming months

Is there a way to use a button-event to change to the next month?
All I've found so far is Show`NextPrevMonth == false`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Well, somebody who#s looking at the calendar should be able to navigate to all upcoming months and back to the current month, but not further back. So, if you're in Nov 2013, the user should be ablte to navigate to all future months (Dec '13, Jan '14, Feb '14, etc.) but NOT to Oct '13. And then come Dec '13, he should be able to see Jan '14, Feb'14 and so on, and be able to navigate to Dec '13 again, but not to Nov '13. I hope it's a little clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `PrevMonthText` property to an empty string e.g.:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" PrevMonthText=""></asp:Calendar>
```

This will effectively hide "view previous month" button, keeping just "view next month" one, so you don't have to invent an extra button for that

If you want to do it only for certain users, you can do the same in code, e.g.

```
if (user == someRestrictedUser) {
    Calendar1.PrevMonthText = string.Empty;
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you need to hide "Previous Month" only when user is in current month, but do show it when use is in future month here're the steps:

Still hide it originally in the markup, but also add handler for `OnVisibleMonthChanged` event:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" PrevMonthText="" OnVisibleMonthChanged="Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged">
</asp:Calendar>
```

In the event handler in addition for user restriction check for calendar's month:

```
protected void Calendar1_VisibleMonthChanged(object sender, MonthChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if (user == someRestrictedUser && e.NewDate.Month == DateTime.Now.Month) {
      Calendar1.PrevMonthText = string.Empty;
   } else {
      Calendar1.PrevMonthText = "&lt;";
   }
}
```

This code will hide "Previous month" only for restricted user and only when user's calendar is in the current month.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks for that, but I didnt really think my question through: I only want the prev-month-button hidden for months that actually have passed. So right now we're in November: So I want to be able to switch to December, January 2014 and so on, but not back to October of this year. So Id like to switch to all upcoming months and back to the current month, but not to months previous to the current month. So something like: if visibleMonth is bigger than current month, show button, if visible month is smaller, hide that button. I hope I didnt express myself too complicated.

Comment: Just a quick note: It should be e.NewDate.Month != DateTime.Now.Month. But otherwise, perfect!

Comment: @user2791739. Glad it worked for you. But actually I put `==` there for a reason. The idea is - when you're in the future months (December etc.) you see both forward and back buttons. But as soon as you hit current month (== November) back button disappears so you can no longer get back, past current month.

Comment: Ah yes, I got that later. I bascially altered it to a version w/o else-clause, I guess. But in case you're still interested: There's a little flaw to your solution when applied to my specific situation. What happens is this: The prev button isnt shown in the current month (so right now Nov 2013) but it isnt shown in Nov 2014 either. But in my case, I really only want it invisible when looking at the current month. I solved that now (after much trying and swearing) by using: e.NewDate.ToString("MM/yyyy") != DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/yyyy")

Comment: Good catch - I haven't considered year. And good solution too to get both month and year together.